# How to print boolean as string in php?

Tags: php

I have a boolean in php. When I do something like :

```
  sprintf('isTrue=%s', isTrue)
    Here isTrue is boolean
```

I get something like `isTrue=1` or `isTrue=`. Is there simple way to get `isTrue=True` or `isTrue=False`

Comment: `(string)true` resolves to `1` in PHP. Why not just `echo 'isTrue=' . ($isTrue ? true : false)`?

Comment: @ceejayoz That's a nice little no-op you have there.

Comment: I actually prefer `var_export` for this: `sprintf('isTrue=%s', var_export(isTrue, true))`

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone Clever!

Answer (score 5):

```
sprintf('isTrue=%s', isTrue ? "True" : "False");
```

Comment: I was looking for Something like this :D Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a little utility function like this perhaps

```
function _bool($b){
    return $b ? 'True' : 'False';
}

echo _bool( $var );
```

Comment: Why are you re-inventing a stripped-down version of `var_export`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure tbh

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $isTrue ? 'true' : 'false';
```

If it `isTrue` is a function that return bool value:

```
echo isTrue() ? 'true' : 'false';
```

To get with data type:

```
$isTrue = false;
var_dump($isTrue);
```